# Renault Clio: Beeping noise when motor is off, but key is turned one notch

Tags: noise, renault, clio

I drive a Renault Clio 3 built in 2011. When the motor is off, but the key is turned one notch clockwise (i.e, power is supplied to things like ventilation, but not to the ignition), there is a beeping noise in the engine compartment. I took a video of it, you can find it here:

https://cloud.tinloaf.de/s/rP38kSbCKCdgQaz

It seems to be the loudest at the upper-left corner of the motor block. The volume is so that if the engine compartment and all doors are closed (but the car and the ventilation are off), it is barely audible in the car.

When I switch the power off (i.e., turn the key into the "completely off" position), there are three clicking noises interrupting the beep, which then stops. You can hear that here (video is not useful since I had to put my phone done in the engine compartment):

https://cloud.tinloaf.de/s/X4abys7yGgoEdPp

Can anybody identify what is making this noise? Is this a reason for concern? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this reply in a German car forum](https://www.motor-talk.de/forum/clio-3-pfeiffendes-geraeusch-aus-dem-motorraum-sobald-der-strom-an-ist-t6895317.html#post59433912), it's the throttle valve, which is controlled using a PWM signal. Apparently, as soon as the engine has power, the valve is brought into a standby position, the PWM signal of which causes the noise. When switching the engine off, the valve is brought into its end positions multiple times (for calibration?), which causes the three "clicks" when turning the engine off.